# created dataframe using R function, but want the results stored as separate variables instead of just printed

Tags: r, dataframe, function

I am building models in R, and want to create a summary table of outputs for each model, specifically the estimates, standard errors and p-values.

Here is my current code with an example data frame and models.

```
speed<-c(0.5,0.1,0.3,0.4,0.9,0.2)
sex<-c(rep(c("F","M"),times=c(3,3)))
mass<-c(500,400,600,800,700,500)
year<-c(2000,2000,2001,2001,2002,2002)
temp.c<-c(0,2,3,1,3,0)
data<-data.frame(speed,sex,mass,year,temp.c)
data

full<-glm(formula = speed ~ sex + mass + year + temp.c, data=data,family=Gamma)
bio<-glm(formula = speed ~ sex + mass, data=data,family=Gamma)
clim<-glm(formula = speed ~ year + temp.c, data=data,family=Gamma)

table.sum<-function(x) {
  
  table.x<-summary(x)
  table.x<-as.data.frame(table.x$coefficients) 
  table.x<-table.x %>% mutate(Estimate=signif(Estimate,2),`Std. Error`= signif(`Std. Error`,2),`t value` = NULL,,`Pr(>|t|)`=signif(`Pr(>|t|)`,digits=2))
  }

mods<-list(full,bio,clim)
lapply(mods,FUN=table.sum)
```

The current code just prints the data frames, like so:

```
[[1]]
            Estimate Std. Error Pr(>|t|)
(Intercept)  2.6e+03    1.1e+04     0.85
sexM         1.6e+00    9.1e+00     0.89
mass        -9.2e-03    2.2e-02     0.75
year        -1.3e+00    5.3e+00     0.85
temp.c       9.4e-02    2.1e+00     0.97

[[2]]
            Estimate Std. Error Pr(>|t|)
(Intercept)  2.6e+03    1.1e+04     0.85
sexM         1.6e+00    9.1e+00     0.89
mass        -9.2e-03    2.2e-02     0.75
year        -1.3e+00    5.3e+00     0.85
temp.c       9.4e-02    2.1e+00     0.97

[[3]]
            Estimate Std. Error Pr(>|t|)
(Intercept)  2.6e+03    1.1e+04     0.85
sexM         1.6e+00    9.1e+00     0.89
mass        -9.2e-03    2.2e-02     0.75
year        -1.3e+00    5.3e+00     0.85
temp.c       9.4e-02    2.1e+00     0.97
```

How do I modify my function so it creates three separate data frames instead of printing them?

Comment: I think many experienced R users would recommend against saving outputs into separate objects in the global environment as an anti-pattern. You can do it, but in most cases that's a good opportunity to rethink your approach. Circle 6 of The R Inferno, "Doing Global Assignments," and the slides here on 20-21 are two references. https://web.eecs.umich.edu/~weimerw/481/lectures/se-16-patterns.pdf

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You use do `list2env` like this:

```
ll <- lapply(mods, FUN=table.sum)
names(ll) <- c("Model 1", "Model 2", "Model 3") # name to whatever you want

list2env(ll, envir = globalenv())
```

Answer (score 2):

We may use

```
library(collapse)
paste0(c("full", "bio", "mass"), "_table") %==% lapply(mods,FUN=table.sum)
```

---

Or with `list2env`

```
my_var <- lapply(mods,FUN=table.sum)
list2env(setNames(my_var, paste0(c("full", "bio", "mass"), "_table")), .GlobalEnv)
```